# google maps api v2 Authentication error

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

Like a lot of people, I'm going in circles. I had an app working fine with Google Maps API v2, and then, maybe through updating Eclipse, the maps stopped working. I have the grey tiles appear, but I get the error:

```
   08-18 11:03:56.678: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7750): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-18 11:03:56.923: D/dalvikvm(7750): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1233K, 15% free 13248K/15495K, paused 2ms+3ms
08-18 11:03:56.968: D/OpenGLRenderer(7750): Flushing caches (mode 0)
08-18 11:03:59.223: D/dalvikvm(7750): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1302K, 14% free 13375K/15495K, paused 4ms+3ms
08-18 11:03:59.538: I/Google Maps Android API(7750): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
08-18 11:04:14.688: E/Google Maps Android API(7750): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I've seen a lot of posts, and I thought I'd covered everything. My manifest reads:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- External storage for caching. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- My Location -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyD8YSb-xzI1CN9EZvfukLvCtioryzDpyg4"/>
         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

My library set-up looks like this:

[image: libraries]

with the following build path:

[image: build path]

Anyone got any ideas where I am going wrong? The API key is the one that worked last time.

Comment: Are you sure your test device has a good connection to the internet? Bad/no connection is one reason you can get the "Failed to contact Google servers" error if you are doing a fresh installation on your test device.

Comment: Thanks - had full wifi and internet access. I think that the issue is to do with the way in which I've set up libraries due to the warning about Google Play Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it, and the problem was in having duplicate keys for the same app on the Google API console. I had created a debug and a release key, but in testing I was only listing the debug key in manifest. By deleting the app's listing from the release key, the maps started to work. 
Strangely enough, I haven't had this problem with duplicate keys before. I also took the Google advice of listing both keys in Manifest, and that didn't work. What seems to work is only one live key in the API console, with only one reference in Manifest.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the same API key, there are two reasons your key might stop working --

1) The package name of your app has changed. Did you change the package name? if so you need to add/update it in your "Allowed Android Apps" to your API key on the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

2) The signing key of your app has changed.  You mentioned you updated eclipse.  You also do not mention if you are using the debug key to sign the app, but is it possible you generated a new debug key for signing?  You can check the debug certificate information by following the instructions in the [maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#displaying_certificate_information).  Then, check your [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) to make sure the fingerprint of your cert is listed correctly.

Comment: Thanks - app is in the allowed list for the API key. I've used the debug key, which, for other users, is viewable through Eclipse Preferences as well as through the terminal command line listing. So I'm stuck! As I said above, I think it's a library set-up problem.